# Machine Gun Etymology Man may have changed tack

Tags: discussion

Recently we've had respite from the Relentless Old Slavonic Etymology Bot, but I think it has been replaced with [a few](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31433/the-meaning-of-ei%C8%9Dte) [similar looking](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31427/what-is-the-name-of-this-middle-english-letter) [questions](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31427/what-is-the-name-of-this-middle-english-letter) that have recently been posted under a few different similar looking usernames.

Is this the same guy? What happened to Old Slavonic Copy Paster to make him switch to old English bibles instead?

Comment: The Bible/Christianity interest is another connection that has been present in some of the older etymology questions also. E.g. [Relation between perfect suffix -()vī and vir](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31405)

Answer (score 8):

They are creating multiple accounts to get around the automatic question bans. These accounts are all from the **past three days!**

https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/24711/stanislavkoshckin
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/24712/anthonsadalsky
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/24714/kostya-dobrov-90
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/24718/fedote-dorofeev
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/24721/tedfedoseev
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/24724/dorofey-fedotov-94

@Mods, can you please look into IP bans or something like that?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, he's been working his way through different archaic languages, searching for some divinity in each one. He was doing the same thing on Latin.SE recently, though I think he's been banned now (or at least I can't find any of his questions any more). And now [he seems to have spread to ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/498282/138581).

My guess on his motives would be something to do with Adamic: that's why he's fixated on Middle English instead of Old English, because afaik there's no complete, surviving Bible in Old English.

EDIT: It seems I spoke too soon. He's back with yet another account, this time hyper-fixated on Koine Greek. He's doing the same thing over on Latin.SE again.